# rogram type already present: com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher

Tags: android, android-volley

[image]
This is sample error Message

[image]
This is sample error Message

Comment: Please don't use image about your code and add further explanation about your aim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my solution to changing this

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'`

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

and it is working for me